# Qt html parsing does not find any tags

Tags: c++, html, qt, html-parsing

I am writing a crawling application. Somewhere in the code Ive got:

```
//normally the HTML is obtained from web with QNetworkAccessManager & QNetworkReply:
//QString htmlCode = this->reply->readAll();  

//exemplary test HTML
QString htmlCode =QString("<html><body><a href=\'foo.bar\'>test1</a><h2>test2<h2><a href=\"bar.foo  \">test3</a></body></html>"); 
QWebPage page;
QWebFrame * frame = page.mainFrame(); //->setHtml(htmlCode);
frame->setHtml(htmlCode);
QWebElement document = frame->documentElement();
QWebElementCollection links = document.findAll("a");
foreach (QWebElement e, links) {
   qDebug() << "exemplary link:" << e.toPlainText();
}
```

I do realize, that there's been like a milion of topics about parsing html in qt here, but i have no idea, what is wrong here...

Comment: What is the issue? No elements or blanks "toPlainText"? [UPD] Oups, the title says it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm... I'm not sure the `setHtml()`works fully synchronously, i.e. I think the frame content is not fully parsed at that time and thus the DOM content is not yet available.

You should try to connect to void `QWebFrame::loadFinished ( bool ok )` and do your DOM crawling there.